# What type to use for things React can render?

Tags: flowtype

I have a component which uses a prop as the rendered component. Since React provides so many ways to create component classes, what should be the type annotation for this prop?

In the example below, what's the correct type annotation for Wrap?

```
import React from 'react'

function Wrap ({ component: Component }) {
  return <Component foo />
}

class ClassComponent extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return <div>foo: {this.props.foo}</div>
  }
}
class ClassPureComponent extends React.PureComponent {
  render () {
    return <div>foo: {this.props.foo}</div>
  }
}

const CreateClassComponent = ReactClass.createClass({
  render () {
    return <div>foo: {this.props.foo}</div>
  }
})

function PureFunctionComponent ({ foo }) {
  return <div>foo: {foo}</div>
}

// These should all be valid
<Wrap component={ClassComponent} />
<Wrap component={ClassPureComponent} />
<Wrap component={CreateClassComponent} />
<Wrap component={PureFunctionComponent} />
```

Comment: The `Wrap` component isn't using the `component` prop.
Is is supposed to render `<Component component={component} />` instead of `<Component foo />`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `ReactClass<any>` is unsafe since it allows

```
<Wrap component={(props: {bar: string}) => <div>{props.bar}</div>} />;
```

Type safe alternative

```
type FunctionComponent<P> = (props: P) => ?React$Element<any>;
type ClassComponentT<D, P, S> = Class<React$Component<D, P, S>>;
type Component<D, P, S> = ClassComponentT<D, P, S> | FunctionComponent<P>;

function Wrap ({ component: Component }: {component: Component<void, { foo: any }, void>}) {
  return <Component foo />
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `ReactClass<any>` is the type you're looking for.

```
// @flow
import React from 'react'

function Wrap ({ component: Component }: {component: ReactClass<any>}) {
  return <Component foo />
}

class ClassComponent extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return <div>foo: {this.props.foo}</div>
  }
}

class ClassPureComponent extends React.PureComponent {
  render () {
    return <div>foo: {this.props.foo}</div>
  }
}

const CreateClassComponent = React.createClass({
  render () {
    return <div>foo: {this.props.foo}</div>
  }
});

function PureFunctionComponent ({ foo }) {
  return <div>foo: {foo}</div>
}

// These should all be valid

<Wrap component={ClassComponent} />;
<Wrap component={ClassPureComponent} />;
<Wrap component={CreateClassComponent} />;
<Wrap component={PureFunctionComponent} />;
```

[Example on flowtype.org/try](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBLAtgBzgJwBcwAlAUwEMBjYqfOLMAcn0pqfSgFcA7GjODzAB1fBRxgAFAG8wVBnh5kehAFxgAwgsHLiAX3XT5uHSvXlqhDTAoBnWwB4KPAJ4A+PQEow01GDCshFz4Qg5aJkoqYFBwcGDAbqh66FQ29ppptuGKumBkAB6EygAmtqRshAB02abEvv6sPMVk+FLe9f4BZEEhYA7FGABubjFwhoQAFhi2lTj0ODOjeg7AA8N+YMnJqKl2ZdZ7AArBZDWRxAVFTWUWNJXHrGe5HY3NrZLtGw3dwaFrI7FxlMZnM4AtKksVv8NlsUoJbMQNKwKEUDvYnlEALzlSyVKjI1GZGQbV4tNo+L5dHp-IYAsY+SbTWbzRaxZarWkwpKeADcnF4-EEYAeZAAYgLCAIeBjiDJorFNp9vtS+v9RoZIRz1ttgMAwAAVCZkWxkMC2CZwLgwYpgCgwGBgABGpsGdowxXQDlE4jk2nOmOkaKyft0enibj5XrEEmMORUAaDIplYYSke9MZD8cDBNOmWT4bT0d9EV0AZF4r4ksE+dTqCAA)

There's an example of a react higher order component [here in the docs](https://flowtype.org/docs/react.html#higher-order-components)