# How to flow type a Component?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

```
type Props = {
  Component: ???
}
const AnotherComp = ({Component}: Props) => (
  <Component />
)
```

What's the proper way to add a prop for the component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type that you're looking for is called `ReactClass`. The type for any component would be `ReactClass<any>`.

Check out this similar question: [What type to use for things React can render?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39561291/what-type-to-use-for-things-react-can-render)

Comment: `ReactClass<*>` is just a little safer (if this fits with the use case)

Comment: `ReactClass<*>` can cause a little trouble if you use it as the type for many different components. For example, as a return type which returns `Foo` from one conditional branch and `Bar` from another branch. Flow will have trouble figuring out what `*` should be for `Foo | Bar`

Answer (score 3):

```
type FunctionComponent<P> = (props: P) => ?React$Element<any>;
type ClassComponent<D, P, S> = Class<React$Component<D, P, S>>;
type Component<D, P, S> = ClassComponent<D, P, S> | FunctionComponent<P>;

type Props = {
  Component: Component<void, {}, void>
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
type Props = {
 Component: React.Component<*>
};
```

## Reference from react type definitions:

```
class React.Component<P = {}, S = {}>
interface React.Component<P = {}, S = {}>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
// Component we want to pass as a prop
class MyComponent extends React.Component<{}> {}

type Props = {
  Component: React.Element<typeof MyComponent>
}

const AnotherComp = ({ Component }: Props) => (
  <Component />
)
```

Link to documentation: https://flow.org/en/docs/react/types/#toc-react-element